# How to improve bayesian logistic regression model with priors

Tags: regression, bayesian, logistic, brms

I'm trying to fit a bayesian logistic regression model to calculate the expected goals (xG) of certain shootings data in football. My model has some simple features where I first fit a model with default settings. I'm trying to understand how I could improve my model but I'm not sure how. Here is a simple model with sample data I'm running using brms with a Bernoulli distribution:

```r
library(brms)
fit <- brm(formula = result_corrected ~ X + Y + angle + dist_to_goal + situation + shotType + lastAction, data = df_man_city_shots,
           family = bernoulli(logit))

summary(fit)
#> Population-Level Effects: 
#>                         Estimate Est.Error   l-95% CI  u-95% CI Rhat Bulk_ESS
#> Intercept               -3343.66   3996.59  -10911.27   3226.14 2.45        5
#> X                          -0.05      0.10      -0.25      0.14 1.14       22
#> Y                          -0.04      0.04      -0.12      0.03 1.16       21
#> angle                       0.00      0.01      -0.02      0.02 1.21       16
#> dist_to_goal               -0.42      0.13      -0.69     -0.20 1.17       17
#> situationFromCorner      3248.78   4005.63   -3239.20  10897.98 2.48        5
#> situationOpenPlay        3244.97   4005.55   -3245.41  10893.62 2.48        5
#> situationPenalty       145622.46  93945.51   30658.58 319582.74 2.41        5
#> situationSetPiece       -9234.21   8778.25  -26718.26   2075.00 1.92        6
#> shotTypeLeftFoot            2.51      2.19      -1.73      6.40 1.31       10
#> shotTypeRightFoot           3.44      2.12      -0.41      6.96 1.45        8
#> lastActionBallRecovery  -5405.41   5949.72  -20137.25    -22.42 1.52        8
#> lastActionBallTouch       106.41    116.85       3.63    401.01 1.94        6
#> lastActionChipped       -6778.05   7179.24  -26803.07   -609.01 3.36        4
#> lastActionCross           102.24    116.95      -0.37    395.28 1.94        6
#> lastActionHeadPass      -8860.15  14256.62  -47614.99   7672.83 1.85        6
#> lastActionLayOff       -32289.83  37942.10 -128562.24   -726.52 1.90        6
#> lastActionNone            104.70    117.05       1.94    399.38 1.94        6
#> lastActionPass            105.51    116.80       3.21    398.52 1.94        6
#> lastActionRebound         105.37    116.86       2.90    398.95 1.93        6
#> lastActionStandard       3356.13   3998.78   -3220.84  10918.26 2.45        5
#> lastActionTakeOn          108.73    117.00       5.94    402.89 1.94        6
#> lastActionThroughball     109.01    116.55       6.44    402.91 1.94        6
#>                        Tail_ESS
#> Intercept                    25
#> X                            71
#> Y                           137
#> angle                        40
#> dist_to_goal                 66
#> situationFromCorner          25
#> situationOpenPlay            25
#> situationPenalty             26
#> situationSetPiece            28
#> shotTypeLeftFoot             41
#> shotTypeRightFoot            35
#> lastActionBallRecovery       14
#> lastActionBallTouch          15
#> lastActionChipped            11
#> lastActionCross              15
#> lastActionHeadPass           11
#> lastActionLayOff             28
#> lastActionNone               15
#> lastActionPass               15
#> lastActionRebound            15
#> lastActionStandard           25
#> lastActionTakeOn             15
#> lastActionThroughball        15
#> 
#> Draws were sampled using sampling(NUTS). For each parameter, Bulk_ESS
#> and Tail_ESS are effective sample size measures, and Rhat is the potential
#> scale reduction factor on split chains (at convergence, Rhat = 1).
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

From my understanding we could check the coefficients of the variables and see that in this case the factor ** situationPenalty** has a big influence on the expected outcome since its high coefficient value. Now I would like to improve my model. I was thinking of setting priors. But I'm not sure how to approach this. So I was wondering if anyone could explain how you could improve a bayesian logistic regression model?

Comment: It will be a challenge to specify informative priors for three categorical variables, and with so many levels. Before getting there though -- the logistic regression fits very poorly. The evidence is in the crazy estimates and the large Rhats. What are X and Y? And what is the purpose of developing this model? (I'm not a sports fan but wouldn't Man City's xG depend on who they play?)

Comment: Hi @dipetkov, Thank you for your comment! X and Y are the coordinates of the shots (they can be removed I think since we already have angle and dist to goal). The purpose of this model is trying to calculate the xG of a shot which tells us if it will be likely that the shot returns in a goal or not. The xG depends on a lot of factors but this is a start to calculate the xG value.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 3 coordinates (location on the pitch + height)? Anyway, the fact remains that the model you have right now didn't converge at all. You could start with a much simpler model (say with X and Y as the only predictors) and iteratively build from there. If this is more of a learning exercise to learn how to do modeling with brms, then it might help to start with a simpler worked-out problem, even if it's less interesting.